# Adding asterisk to shorthand in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, highlighting

I searched all sources I know but I couldn't seem to find a solution to my problem. The background of my question is that I want to mark some of my references with an asterisk because their authors are very good. I want to mark the shorthand because the reader should know that the reference is special when they read through the document.

What I have at the moment is the following MWE (I got it from this forum).

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} 

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{bohec,
  author        = {Le Bohec, Yann},
  title         = {Histoire militaire des guerres puniques},
  date          = {1996},
  location      = {Monaco},
  publisher     = {Rocher},
  isbn          = {2-268-02147-5},
}
@book{uthor,
  author        = {Uthor, Arnold},
  title         = {A Book},
  date          = {2013},
  location      = {Place},
  publisher     = {P. Ublisher's \& Co.},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{asterisk}

\renewbibmacro*{bibindex}{%
  \ifbibindex
    {\indexnames{labelname}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}
  \ifcategory{asterisk}%
    {*}%
    {}}


\begin{document}
  \addtocategory{asterisk}{uthor,bohec}
  \cite{wilde,cicero,coleridge,vangennep,bohec,uthor}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output.

[image: Current output]

I want the asterisks in the reference list not to be right before the first author but in the shorthand, like so (reproduced with MS Word):

[image: Wanted output]

Do you have an idea how to achieve this? I would be highly grateful for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\ifcategory{asterisk}{#1*}{#1}}
```

In full:

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} 

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{bohec,
  author        = {Le Bohec, Yann},
  title         = {Histoire militaire des guerres puniques},
  date          = {1996},
  location      = {Monaco},
  publisher     = {Rocher},
  isbn          = {2-268-02147-5},
}
@book{uthor,
  author        = {Uthor, Arnold},
  title         = {A Book},
  date          = {2013},
  location      = {Place},
  publisher     = {P. Ublisher's \& Co.},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{asterisk}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\ifcategory{asterisk}{#1*}{#1}}

\begin{document}
  \addtocategory{asterisk}{uthor,bohec}
  \cite{wilde,cicero,coleridge,vangennep,bohec,uthor}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]