# Biblatex: Marking reference categories with different symbols

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, highlighting

A journal I would like to submit to requires that references of "special" and "outstanding" interest be labelled with one or two asterisks, respectively, as follows:

```
This is a normal reference [1].
This is a special reference [2*].
This is an outstanding reference [3**].
```

I've managed to create the "special" one-asterisk category following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407070/adding-asterisk-to-shorthand-in-biblatex). However, if I try to create two categories, only one of the two is formatted as I'd like it to be. Is there a better method to create reference categories with customised formatting?

My reference MWE:

```
@Article{Bolton1982,
    author  = {Bolton, David C and McKinley, Michael P and Prusiner, Stanley B},
    journal = {Science},
    title   = {Identification of a protein that purifies with the scrapie prion},
}

@Article{Basler1986,
    author  = {Basler, K and Oesch, B and Scott, M and Westaway, D and Wälchli, M and Groth, DF and McKinley, MP and Prusiner, SB and Weissmann, C},
    journal = {Cell},
    title   = {Scrapie and cellular PrP isoforms are encoded by the same chromosomal gene},
}

@Article{Scheckel2018,
    author  = {Scheckel, C. and Aguzzi, A.},
    journal = {Nat Rev Genet},
    title   = {Prions, prionoids and protein misfolding disorders},
}
```

My document MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\let\origcite\cite%
\def\cite#1{\unskip~\origcite{#1}}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\addbibresource{my_references.bib}

%declare categories
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{special}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\ifcategory{special}{#1*}{#1}}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{outstanding}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\ifcategory{outstanding}{#1**}{#1}}


\begin{document}

%reference categories
\addtocategory{special}{Bolton1982}
\addtocategory{outstanding}{Basler1986}

\parencite{Bolton1982}
\parencite{Basler1986}
\parencite{Scheckel2018}


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subsequent `\DeclareFieldFormat` calls overwrite each other, so only the last call wins.

You will have to combine the two definitions

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\ifcategory{special}{#1*}{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\ifcategory{outstanding}{#1**}{#1}}
```

into one

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{%
  \ifcategory{outstanding}
    {#1**}
    {\ifcategory{special}
       {#1*}
       {#1}}}
```

Then

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{special}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{outstanding}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{%
  \ifcategory{outstanding}
    {#1**}
    {\ifcategory{special}
       {#1*}
       {#1}}}

\addtocategory{special}{geer}
\addtocategory{outstanding}{sigfridsson}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson}
\autocite{worman}
\autocite{geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields

[image: [1**] [2] [3*]]

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks!